# Multiple variables in email subject : Magento 2

Tags: email-templates, magento2.4

I would like to add multiple variable in email subject but the problem only one is taking into consideration.

```
<!--@subject {{trans "%name, see the hint from %sender" name=$name, sender=$sender_name}} @-->
```

Any idea how to implement it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the "," (comma) after the `name=$name` variable.

[Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/445b0f1a3d6a91b5da32d311077c2112ef0b1503/app/code/Magento/User/view/adminhtml/email/user_notification.html#L7) you can find an example from a core template.